# unable to comiple Qt app on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, kde, qt, c++, konsole

I wrote some Qt application that makes use of `Konsole` and for that to work, I need to `#include <KParts/Part>` but the problem is, I keep getting `/home/ron/src/kterminal/terminal.h:25:23: fatal error: KParts/Part: No such file or directory` which package am I missing to get this compiled?

Comment: Maybe [libkf5parts-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libkf5parts-dev/filelist)? You will likely need an appropriate `-I` compiler directive as well e.g. `-I /usr/include/KF5/KParts/`

Comment: @steeldriver I had `libkf5parts-dev` installed already. Why would I need a compiler directive on this setup where this code on my `Kubuntu` system compiles just fine?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to say without more information about your two systems and your build process. Perhaps the packages install to different paths?

Comment: @steeldriver actually no, the file is on both systems at `/usr/include/KF5/KParts/kparts/part.h` ...

Comment: I'm confused - `kparts/part.h` is not the same file as `KParts/Part` (one is likely a C header and the other a C++ header) - which are you actually having difficulty with?

Comment: @steeldriver hoops, yes sorry! The problem header is `/usr/include/KF5/KParts/KParts/Part` which I just confirmed is on both system at that location...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46875/discussion-between-cerr-and-steeldriver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reboot my system in order for the new headers to be accepted and the project to compile flawlessy.

Comment: @luchonacho as it is the OP telling us he doesn't need the quiestion any more I'd say, it is an answer.